# Why wont my viewDidLoad method execute?

Tags: iphone, load, modal-dialog, tabbar, viewdidload

I have an iPhone app, with a tab bar controller. Before the tab bar is loaded, I present a modal view for registration. Once registration is completed this view is dismissed, and the tabs appear, with the "News" tab selected. For some reason, even though the News view is displaying, the viewDidLoad method of the News class is not being called.

I know I am probably missing something simple, I'm kind of a noob at iPhone programming. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the 'News' view to the tabbar? eg:

```
[tabBarController setViewControllers:
                           [NSArray arrayWithObjects:newsController, nil]];
```

Just trying to make sure that you're not missing stuff :)

Comment: Well, I figured it out! :) 

Not quite sure what the issue was. I messed around with interface builder, saved and it worked. Thanks for the answer anyway!